# Fetching from GET action PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a HTML form for `ID` and PHP files. 
Upon entering the `ID` , I want to fetch the `ID` from PHP files .
Though I have included `<form action ="./index.php" method="get">` 
I am not able to fetch data . 
I have used JSON scripts in PHP files.

Here is the PHP form `index.php`

```html
<!--search-box-->
<div class="search-box">
    <form action="./index.php" method="get">
 <input class="sb-search-input input__field--madoka" name="teamid" placeholder="Enter Your Team ID" type="search" id="input-31" />
    </form>
</div><!--//end-search-box-->
```

Here is the php scripts named as `index.html`

```html
id == $PLAYERCODE) { return($playbas->web_name); } } } function GETPLAYERPOSITION($id) { $PLAYERCODE=$id; $playbasic=file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/elements/"); $playerbasic=json_decode($playbasic); foreach ($playerbasic as $playbas) { IF ($playbas->id == $PLAYERCODE) { return($playbas->element_type); } } } function GETPLAYERFIXPOINTS($id,$fix) { $PLAYERCODE=$id; $ROUND=$fix; $play=file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/element-summary/".$PLAYERCODE); $playerdata=json_decode($play); foreach ($playerdata->history as $plays) { IF ($plays->round == $ROUND) { return($plays->total_points); } } } $TEAMCODE=81882; $string = file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/entry/".$TEAMCODE); $x=json_decode($string); $currentGW= $x->entry->current_event; echo '***************************************
'; echo '********* Header Information *********
'; echo '***************************************
'; echo 'Team Name: '.$x->entry->name.'
'; echo 'Overall Rank: '.$x->entry->summary_overall_rank.'
'; echo 'Overall Points: '.$x->entry->summary_overall_points.'
'; echo 'Team Value: '.(intval($x->entry->value+$x->entry->bank)/10).'
'; echo 'Total Transfers: '.$x->entry->total_transfers.'
'; echo '***************************************
'; echo '********* Player Game Week Data *********
'; echo '***************************************
'; $TOTAL_TRANSFER_COST=0; $TOTAL_CAPTAIN_POINTS=0; $TOTAL_BENCH_POINTS=0; $GW_BEST_CAPTAIN=0; $TOTAL_BEST_CAPTAIN_POINTS=0; $TOTAL_BEST_POSSIBLE_POINTS=0; $ORH=array(); $GRH=array(); $TVH=array(); $RSH=array(); $PSH=array(); $i=1; while ($i <= $currentGW) { $PICKS=file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/entry/".$TEAMCODE."/event/".$i."/picks"); $weekdata=json_decode($PICKS); echo '
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
'; echo 'GW: '.$i.'
'; echo 'GW Average Score: '.$weekdata->event->average_entry_score.'
'; echo 'GW Score: '.$weekdata->entry_history->points.'
'; echo 'GW Total Score: '.$weekdata->entry_history->total_points.'
'; echo 'GW Rank: '.$weekdata->entry_history->rank.'
'; echo 'GW Overall Rank: '.$weekdata->entry_history->overall_rank.'
'; echo 'GW Transfers: '.$weekdata->entry_history->event_transfers.'
'; echo 'GW Transfers Cost: '.$weekdata->entry_history->event_transfers_cost.'
'; echo 'GW Team Value: '.(($weekdata->entry_history->value+$weekdata->entry_history->bank)/10).'
'; echo 'GW Bench Points: '.$weekdata->entry_history->points_on_bench.'
'; $TOTAL_TRANSFER_COST=$TOTAL_TRANSFER_COST+$weekdata->entry_history->event_transfers_cost; $TOTAL_BENCH_POINTS=$TOTAL_BENCH_POINTS+$weekdata->entry_history->points_on_bench; $GW_BEST_CAPTAIN=0; $GW_CAPTAIN_POINTS=0; $BESTMULTI=1; $GK=array(); $CB=array(); $CM=array(); $FW=array(); $F=array(); foreach ($weekdata->picks as $pick) { $PLAYERPOINTS=GETPLAYERFIXPOINTS($pick->element,$i); $PLAYERPOSITION=GETPLAYERPOSITION($pick->element); $BESTMULTI=$BESTMULTI*$pick->multiplier; if ($GW_BEST_CAPTAIN<$PLAYERPOINTS) { $GW_BEST_CAPTAIN=$PLAYERPOINTS; } if ($pick->is_captain==1) { $GW_CAPTAIN_POINTS=$pick->multiplier*GETPLAYERFIXPOINTS($pick->element,$i); $TOTAL_CAPTAIN_POINTS=$TOTAL_CAPTAIN_POINTS+$GW_CAPTAIN_POINTS; } if ($PLAYERPOSITION==1) { $GK[count($GK)]=$PLAYERPOINTS; } if ($PLAYERPOSITION==2) { $CB[count($CB)]=$PLAYERPOINTS; } if ($PLAYERPOSITION==3) { $CM[count($CM)]=$PLAYERPOINTS; } if ($PLAYERPOSITION==4) { $FW[count($FW)]=$PLAYERPOINTS; } } $TOTAL_BEST_CAPTAIN_POINTS=$TOTAL_BEST_CAPTAIN_POINTS+$GW_BEST_CAPTAIN*$BESTMULTI; $i=$i+1; rsort($GK); rsort($CB); rsort($CM); rsort($FW); /* $F352 */ $F[0]=$GK[0]+$CB[0]+$CB[1]+$CB[2]+$CM[0]+$CM[1]+$CM[2]+$CM[3]+$CM[4]+$FW[0]+$FW[1]; /* $F343= */ $F[1]=$GK[0]+$CB[0]+$CB[1]+$CB[2]+$CM[0]+$CM[1]+$CM[2]+$CM[3]+$FW[0]+$FW[1]+$FW[2]; /* $F451= */ $F[2]=$GK[0]+$CB[0]+$CB[1]+$CB[2]+$CB[3]+$CM[0]+$CM[1]+$CM[2]+$CM[3]+$CM[4]+$FW[0]; /* $F442= */ $F[3]=$GK[0]+$CB[0]+$CB[1]+$CB[2]+$CB[3]+$CM[0]+$CM[1]+$CM[2]+$CM[3]+$FW[0]; /* $F433= */ $F[4]=$GK[0]+$CB[0]+$CB[1]+$CB[2]+$CB[3]+$CM[0]+$CM[1]+$CM[2]+$FW[0]+$FW[1]+$FW[2]; /* $F541= */ $F[5]=$GK[0]+$CB[0]+$CB[1]+$CB[2]+$CB[3]+$CB[4]+$CM[0]+$CM[1]+$CM[2]+$CM[3]+$FW[0]; /* $F532= */ $F[6]=$GK[0]+$CB[0]+$CB[1]+$CB[2]+$CB[3]+$CB[4]+$CM[0]+$CM[1]+$CM[2]+$FW[0]+$FW[1]; /* $F523= */ $F[7]=$GK[0]+$CB[0]+$CB[1]+$CB[2]+$CB[3]+$CB[4]+$CM[0]+$CM[1]+$FW[0]+$FW[1]+$FW[2]; rsort($F); echo 'GW CAPTAIN POINT: '.$GW_CAPTAIN_POINTS; echo '
GW BEST POSSIBLE CAPTAIN POINT: '.$GW_BEST_CAPTAIN*$BESTMULTI; echo '
GW BEST POSSIBLE POINTS: '.($F[0]+($GW_BEST_CAPTAIN*($BESTMULTI-1))); $TOTAL_BEST_POSSIBLE_POINTS=$TOTAL_BEST_POSSIBLE_POINTS+$F[0]+($GW_BEST_CAPTAIN*($BESTMULTI-1)); $ORH[count($ORH)]=$weekdata->entry_history->overall_rank; $GRH[count($GRH)]=$weekdata->entry_history->rank; $TVH[count($TVH)]=(($weekdata->entry_history->value+$weekdata->entry_history->bank)/10); $RSH[count($RSH)]=$weekdata->entry_history->points; $PSH[count($PSH)]=$F[0]+($GW_BEST_CAPTAIN*($BESTMULTI-1)); } echo '

total transfer cost: '.$TOTAL_TRANSFER_COST.'
'; echo 'total Captain Points: '.$TOTAL_CAPTAIN_POINTS.'
'; echo 'total Bench Points: '.$TOTAL_BENCH_POINTS.'
'; echo 'total Possible Captain Points: '.$TOTAL_BEST_CAPTAIN_POINTS.'
'; echo 'total Team Best Possible Points: '.$TOTAL_BEST_POSSIBLE_POINTS.'
'; echo 'ORH
'; echo $ORH[0].'
'; echo $ORH[1].'
'; echo $ORH[2].'
'; echo $ORH[3].'
'; echo 'GRH
'; echo $GRH[0].'
'; echo $GRH[1].'
'; echo $GRH[2].'
'; echo $GRH[3].'
'; echo 'TVH
'; echo $TVH[0].'
'; echo $TVH[1].'
'; echo $TVH[2].'
'; echo $TVH[3].'
'; echo 'RSH
'; echo $RSH[0].'
'; echo $RSH[1].'
'; echo $RSH[2].'
'; echo $RSH[3].'
'; echo 'PSH
'; echo $PSH[0].'
'; echo $PSH[1].'
'; echo $PSH[2].'
'; echo $PSH[3].'
'; ?>
```

Comment: PHP engine can't parse the `.html` file

Comment: @JYoThI But If i rename it, there will be two `index.php` How to resolve that ? Should I place them under different folder in server?

Comment: + I did change the extrension and upon entering `ID` on the search box , it takes me to page full of PHP script, Thats `index.php` , Why isnt the php file being processed?

Answer (score 0):

First check if php on your server is configured well. Make some small php script that i.e. prints only phpinfo():

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
```

Name it i.e. `info.php` or something and call the script. If this is not working then problem is not in your script but in server configuration. It may be miss configured or not even installed at all.

Comment: Yes Sir. Its working. I can see all the php info here is the [link](http://statistics.fplnepal.com/draft/info.php)

Comment: If that it means php is working well. You didn't show us your script from the beginning. How did you open php tag? Maybe you used short php opening tag?

Comment: Those were only the PHP codes .  I included on main post. Is the code missing? I can run it, I am getting result, but its not coming out in HTML layout, just in plain format.

Comment: Your code is starting with "id == $PLAYERCODE) { return($playbas->web_name); } } } function GETPLAYERPOSITION($id) { $PLAYERCODE=$id; ...."